# Issue in HFP/HSP bluetooth profile in Linux

Tags: linux, audio, bluetooth, embedded

I am attempting to implement hands-free telephony on my board, I successfully connected my android phone to the board via bluetooth module(QCA61X4A) in phone and media audio sharing mode.

I was able to play media files via bluetooth by this. But when a call connected the bluetooth speaker works properly, i.e. I can hear what is said on the Mobile Phone, but audio is not transmitted from Board to Mobile Phone is not heard ( I guess there is some error in getting the data from mic or in transmitting data from bluetooth device). I get the following log message keeps appearing many times as soon as a call is initiated

"***Bluetooth: hci0 SCO packet for unknown connection handle 0***

***Bluetooth: hci0 sending frame failed (-27)***

***Bluetooth: hci0 sending frame failed (-27)***"

The Bluetooth device is connected via USB interface, Below is the device package configuration,
pulseaudio --version

pulseaudio 11.1
 bluetoothctl --version
bluetoothctl: 5.49

ofonod --version
1.22
https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/Documentation/User/Bluetooth/

In the above link section 5 they have mentioned to enable SCO routing using hcitool command, But i dont know the command for QCA61X4A chipset. Could someone help me on this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Issue got resolved by assigned proper sink source audio path using pacmd command.

Refer below link for reference, I used

> pacmd move-sink-input < INPUTID> < SINKNAME>

[PulseAudio commands](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples)

Comment: Thanks for following up your question with an answer. For the benefit of future readers: what was the correct sink source audio path, and which command did you use?

Comment: @bertieb I have updated the Answer.